# Pika, Select Adapter and gevent

Tags: python, gevent, pika

Does anybody know if it is safe to use `pika` with `gevent` using the `SelectConnection` adaptor?

Looking at the code, I don't see why not. As far as I can tell it just calls `select.epoll()` which I assume it is patched by `monkey.patch_all()`.

Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard `SelectConnection` in combination with `gevent` *kind-of works*, but **badly**. The problem is that it does not integrate with the gevent event loop.
In one case we have experienced, this means that a consumer will get a pause waiting for the connection poll to time out. This is by default 5.0 seconds. This will cause severe degradations in performance. Instead, **use GeventConnection**.